# fridge warm and freezer cold

Tags: refrigerator, freezing

My fridge is warm and my freezer is really cold and freezing things a lot. The things in the fridge are soft or bad. Why will this be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the freezer is where the "cooling" coils are, heat is exchanged with the refrigerator compartment through interconnecting vents (sometimes fans assist with air movement). The vent ports are often adjustable.

Sometimes these vent ports get iced up, this is a very common cause for the description of your problem. Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8g_39UHYeEA).

Comment: I ended up buying a new fridge because I don't how old it is because it was the previous tenants.

Answer (score 0):

Bad defrost timer, defrost temp sensor or a bad defrost heater. Add these to the vents being blocked. One test for the timer is to manually advance it slowly until the fridge stops running. Wait for about 15-30 minutes. If it starts back up, then your timer is good. Next test would be the temp sensor. It is attached to the defrost heater in the freezer. This will tell the heater to turn on to "defrost" the unit. Best option here to test is to remove the freezer interior panel (unplug the fridge before removing the panel) and do the timer advance trick. If the sensor works, you will see ice melt, unless the heater is bad. To test the sensor, you need a voltmeter set to ohms. Use a cup of hot water and a cup of ice water. Disconnect the sensor and hook up your meter and dip the sensor in the cups, alternating between the cups and monitoring the meter scale. If it changes then most likely the sensor is good. The next would be the defrost heater. Again, if it works, you should see ice melting.